# Setting Encoding format to java in shell Script

Tags: java, linux, shell

I have a shell script which runs My Java Application.Now i want to specify encoding format "UTF8" to my java application using shell script can any one help.I am using mac os.

Thanks
Ganesh

Comment: What do you mean by "specify encoding format "UTF8" to my java application"?

Answer (score 13):

Try

```
//invoking the compiler when your source code contains naked UTF-8 characters.
javac.exe -encoding UTF-8  MyClass.java
```

and

```
//setting the default encoding on the command line
java.exe "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" -jar myprog.jar
```

source:  http://mindprod.com/jgloss/encoding.html