# How can you make the pound sterling sign (£) show in the command prompt from a java program?

Tags: java

I'm having trouble getting the £ sign to show properly in the command prompt after doing:

System.out.println("The price from x to y is £4");

When executed in the command prompt it reads : The price from x to y is ú4

Comment: What is the defualt character encoding for your system?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426171/setting-encoding-format-to-java-in-shell-script/4426219#4426219

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747358/java-unicode-confusion/

Comment: Possibly useful reading material: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: The problem with displaying non-ASCII characters is that in any given situation there's about five places things can go wrong and it's impossible to tell how to solve your problem without determining what went wrong. I.e. whether the problem is that your text editor saves in a different encoding than the compiler inputs, or that your console is using a different encoding than Java is printing, etc. Basically, at every text input/output interface, **both** sides have to use the same encoding, and plain text usually doesn't afford the metadata to specify it.

Comment: @ Adam:  There is terminal emulator called mintty on windows which handles this cleanly. It would have worked fine on linux

Comment: Oh and to add insult to injury, I believe that Windows command prompts still default to a legacy codepage instead of Unicode. (And I'm absolutely not sure whether Java will detect that you've set the console encoding to UTF-8, so you might be hosed if the encoding that it's set to simply doesn't have the pound character.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to supply a Unicode value in the string for the pound symbol.

You should do:

```
System.console().writer().println("The price from x to y is \u00A34");
```

See [this page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/convertintro.html) for more information.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747358/java-unicode-confusion).

Comment: Wrong. It's a console ANSI-OEM conversion problem, not a problem with source encoding.

Comment: @axtavt, you cannot say for sure.  Perhaps the source code was entered in an editor using a different codepage than expected by javac.

Comment: @retrodome, perhaps that should be `\u0A34` ;) but `£` should do the same thing.

Comment: @Peter, no sorry 00A3 is the unicode for £. The trailing 4 is the numeric value from his question.

Answer (score 2):

I Windows run

```
chcp 1252
```

in your command prompt first.

Answer (score 2):

The only variant which works for me:

```
System.out.println((char) 339);
```